# dplyr - filter rows prior to a certain condition, and expanding non-contiguous time values

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a series of position and personnel changes in a HR data set. The data set represents a history of personnel movements within a given set of `positionIDs`.

```
df <- structure(list(index = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39), positionID = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6), personID = c(114, 
115, 113, 109, 108, 108, 100, 108, 100, 108, 101, 110, 110, 110, 
110, 103, 102, 112, 112, 112, 102, 102, 117, 102, 107, 107, 104, 
109, 118, 118, 105, 118, 118, 111, 106, 106, 120, 120, 120), 
    moveStartDate = c("1/07/2021", "4/07/2021", "28/06/2021", 
    "17/01/2022", "15/04/2022", "7/05/2022", "1/07/2022", "1/07/2022", 
    "26/07/2022", "26/07/2022", "31/12/2020", "1/10/2020", "1/01/2021", 
    "1/01/2021", "28/01/2021", "31/03/2021", "1/07/2021", "19/07/2021", 
    "30/04/2022", "3/06/2022", "1/02/2022", "1/07/2022", "29/08/2022", 
    "24/09/2022", "1/07/2021", "20/08/2021", "5/10/2020", "1/08/2022", 
    "8/08/2022", "7/09/2022", "2/10/2022", "14/10/2022", "29/10/2022", 
    "16/10/2020", "1/08/2020", "22/12/2020", "31/01/2022", "24/12/2022", 
    "3/02/2023"), moveEndDate = c("4/07/2021", "4/07/2021", "17/10/2021", 
    "14/04/2022", "6/05/2022", "30/06/2022", "25/07/2022", "25/07/2022", 
    "30/09/2022", "31/12/2022", "31/12/2020", "31/12/2020", "27/01/2021", 
    "27/01/2021", NA, "31/01/2022", "31/01/2022", "29/04/2022", 
    "3/06/2022", "3/06/2022", "30/06/2022", "23/09/2022", "25/09/2022", 
    "31/03/2023", "20/08/2021", "20/08/2021", "1/12/2021", "28/10/2022", 
    "6/09/2022", "30/09/2022", "2/10/2022", "28/10/2022", NA, 
    "16/10/2020", "21/12/2020", "21/12/2021", "23/12/2022", "2/02/2023", 
    NA), moveType = c("temporary appointment", "moved agency", 
    "temporary appointment", "transfer", "transfer", "transfer", 
    "redesignation", "transfer", "redesignation", "redesignation", 
    "moved agency", "relief", "relief", "transfer", "promotion", 
    "redesignation", "transfer", "transfer", "relief", "resignation", 
    "transfer", "transfer", "temporary appointment", "transfer", 
    "relief", "moved agency", "restructure", "relief", "relief", 
    "relief", "end of contract", "relief", "relief", "moved agency", 
    "relief", "promotion", "relief", "relief", "relief"), exitCode = c(NA, 
    "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, "B", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, "E", NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-39L), class = "data.frame")
```

- Each position has a unique `positionID` Each staff member has a
  unique `personID` Each position can have different staff moved in and
  out over time. For example a person could resign or take extended
  leave and be replaced with a different `personID`.
- If the `personID` leaves the organisation they will have an exit code. Internal
  movements with exiting are `NA`.
- The movement dates are ordered
  sequentially, and if the person is still in the position, they do not
  have a move end date.

There are two problems I am trying to solve, as follows:

First problem:

- I would like to filter the set such that only `positionID`s where there is an exit code and the subsequent `moveTypes` of each `positionID` are retained.
- I tried a `group_by` for `positonID` and `moveEndDate` to create a sequence of increments within each group. This created the increments, but I would not exclude the rows in each group prior to the non-NA `exitCode`. Within this group I would like to exclude any rows prior to the first `exitCode`.
- What I want to is create a new group where the `moveEndDate` starts at the point where there is an `exitCode`. For example `positonID` 1 group would include all rows from `personID` 115 until designated to `personID` 108 on 31/12/2022.

Second problem:

The time periods between a `moveEndDate` and a subsequent `moveStart` date are not contiguous. For example indexes 31 and 32. I would like to be able to insert a row that has a `moveStartDate` that is equal to the `moveEndDate + 1day` for immediate prior `moveEndDate` for that row, and a move `endEndDate` for the next `moveStart` date in the group (if there is one).
I’ll be honest. I don’t even know where to start with this one.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: First part could be taken care of using `df %>% group_by(positionID) %>% filter(cumsum(!is.na(exitCode)) >= 1)` but the second part is beyond me, sorry

Comment: The second problem is a bit unclear to me, can you show the expected output for the case of indices 31 and 32?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With all credit to @jared_mamrot for the first part - see their comment above - you can `filter()` on `cumsum()` to very neatly achieve what you want:

```
x <-
  df %>%
  group_by(positionID) %>%
  filter(cumsum(!is.na(exitCode)) >= 1)
```

For the second part, I can suggest a solution based on my understanding of your description of the problem. That is, you want to insert the new row between each row pair where the number of days (the "gap") between the `moveEndDate` and subsequent `moveStartDate` is greater than zero. (So cases having a negative gap are ignored.) Note that this operates within a given `positionID`.

We can continue from where left off above, having created a new data.frame `x` and removed the unwanted rows. We again group by `positionID` and create a couple of new columns, using `lead()` to allow us to easily compare the current `moveEndDate` and subsequent `moveStartDate`. (Note we are using the `lubridate` package here.)

```
library(lubridate)

x <-
  x %>%
  group_by(positionID) %>%
  mutate(
    nextStartDate = lead(moveStartDate),
    gapToNextStartDate = (dmy(nextStartDate) - dmy(moveEndDate)) %>% as.numeric()
  )
```

... which gives us (first five rows shown):

```
  index positionID personID moveStartDate moveEndDate moveType              exitCode nextStartDate gapToNextStartDate
  <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>         <chr>       <chr>                 <chr>    <chr>                      <dbl>
1     2          1      115 4/07/2021     4/07/2021   moved agency          A        28/06/2021                    -6
2     3          1      113 28/06/2021    17/10/2021  temporary appointment NA       17/01/2022                    92
3     4          1      109 17/01/2022    14/04/2022  transfer              NA       15/04/2022                     1
4     5          1      108 15/04/2022    6/05/2022   transfer              NA       7/05/2022                      1
5     6          1      108 7/05/2022     30/06/2022  transfer              NA       1/07/2022                      1
```

We are interested in those rows having `gapToNextStartDate` (in days) being positive. It is after these rows that we want to insert our new rows.

This next section is inelegant but should do the trick. Not knowing what you wish to set certain columns in the new rows I've made them `NA`, with the exception of `moveType` which I've set to "*** inserted row ***" just to highlight these newly inserted rows.

```
# create a new data frame having the same columns but zero rows
out <- x[0, ]

for (i in seq_len(nrow(x))) {

  # add the current row from x to the output data.frame
  out <- bind_rows(out, x[i, ])  
   
  # check if we need to insert a new row after this one,
  # based on the condition of a positive number of days between
  # this row's moveEndDate and the next row's moveStartDate
  # (within a given positionID)
  if (!is.na(x[i, ]$gapToNextStartDate) & x[i, ]$gapToNextStartDate > 0) {
    out <-
      bind_rows(
        out,
        data.frame(
          index = NA,
          positionID = x[i, ]$positionID,
          personID = NA,
          moveStartDate = (dmy(x[i, ]$moveEndDate) + 1) %>% format("%d/%m/%Y"),
          moveEndDate = x[i, ]$nextStartDate,
          moveType = "*** inserted row ***",
          exitCode = NA,
          nextStartDate = NA,
          gapNextStartDate = NA
        )
      )
  }
}
```

Our original data frame `x` had 31 rows (after executing 'part one') - we have now added an additional 15 rows for cases meeting the condition as described above. The first ten rows of the output `out` are shown:

```
   index positionID personID moveStartDate moveEndDate moveType              exitCode nextStartDate gapToNextStar…¹ gapNe…²
   <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>         <chr>       <chr>                 <chr>    <chr>                   <dbl> <lgl>  
 1     2          1      115 4/07/2021     4/07/2021   moved agency          A        28/06/2021                 -6 NA     
 2     3          1      113 28/06/2021    17/10/2021  temporary appointment NA       17/01/2022                 92 NA     
 3    NA          1       NA 18/10/2021    17/01/2022  *** inserted row ***  NA       NA                         NA NA     
 4     4          1      109 17/01/2022    14/04/2022  transfer              NA       15/04/2022                  1 NA     
 5    NA          1       NA 15/04/2022    15/04/2022  *** inserted row ***  NA       NA                         NA NA     
 6     5          1      108 15/04/2022    6/05/2022   transfer              NA       7/05/2022                   1 NA     
 7    NA          1       NA 07/05/2022    7/05/2022   *** inserted row ***  NA       NA                         NA NA     
 8     6          1      108 7/05/2022     30/06/2022  transfer              NA       1/07/2022                   1 NA     
 9    NA          1       NA 01/07/2022    1/07/2022   *** inserted row ***  NA       NA                         NA NA     
10     7          1      100 1/07/2022     25/07/2022  redesignation         NA       1/07/2022                 -24 NA
```

The temporary columns `nextStartDate` and `gapToNextStartDate` have been retained for clarity but could be removed. Desired values for `index`, `personID`, etc. could be added if necessary.

**Note:** Most of the cases where gaps occur have a gap of a single day. I've assumed these fit your description of "non-contiguous", but if not they could be easily ignored by modifying `> 0` to `> 1`.

Answer (score 1):

First change the date columns to `Date`s:

```
library(dplyr) # >= v1.1.0
library(lubridate)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(across(moveStartDate:moveEndDate, dmy))
```

For your first problem, filter using `dplyr::cumany()`, `.by` `PositionID`:

```
df <- df %>%
  filter(cumany(!is.na(exitCode)), .by = positionID)
```

For your second problem, bring in the next start date using `dplyr::lead()`, filter to rows with >1 day difference, manipulate the dates to fill the gap, and bind back to your original dataframe. You can then `arrange()` and re-compute the `index` column.

```
gaps <- df %>%
  group_by(positionID) %>%
  mutate(nextStartDate = lead(moveStartDate)) %>%
  filter(nextStartDate - moveEndDate > days(1)) %>%
  transmute(
    moveStartDate = moveEndDate + days(1),
    moveEndDate = nextStartDate
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
  
df <- df %>%
  bind_rows(gaps) %>%
  arrange(positionID, moveEndDate) %>%
  mutate(index = row_number())
```

Result:

```
#> print(as_tibble(df), n = 35)
# A tibble: 35 × 7
   index positionID personID moveStartDate moveEndDate moveType         exitCode
   <int>      <dbl>    <dbl> <date>        <date>      <chr>            <chr>   
 1     1          1      115 2021-07-04    2021-07-04  moved agency     A       
 2     2          1      113 2021-06-28    2021-10-17  temporary appoi… <NA>    
 3     3          1       NA 2021-10-18    2022-01-17  <NA>             <NA>    
 4     4          1      109 2022-01-17    2022-04-14  transfer         <NA>    
 5     5          1      108 2022-04-15    2022-05-06  transfer         <NA>    
 6     6          1      108 2022-05-07    2022-06-30  transfer         <NA>    
 7     7          1      100 2022-07-01    2022-07-25  redesignation    <NA>    
 8     8          1      108 2022-07-01    2022-07-25  transfer         <NA>    
 9     9          1      100 2022-07-26    2022-09-30  redesignation    <NA>    
10    10          1      108 2022-07-26    2022-12-31  redesignation    <NA>    
11    11          2      101 2020-12-31    2020-12-31  moved agency     A       
12    12          2      110 2020-10-01    2020-12-31  relief           <NA>    
13    13          2      110 2021-01-01    2021-01-27  relief           <NA>    
14    14          2      110 2021-01-01    2021-01-27  transfer         <NA>    
15    15          2      110 2021-01-28    NA          promotion        <NA>    
16    16          3      112 2022-06-03    2022-06-03  resignation      B       
17    17          3      102 2022-02-01    2022-06-30  transfer         <NA>    
18    18          3      102 2022-07-01    2022-09-23  transfer         <NA>    
19    19          3      117 2022-08-29    2022-09-25  temporary appoi… <NA>    
20    20          3      102 2022-09-24    2023-03-31  transfer         <NA>    
21    21          4      107 2021-08-20    2021-08-20  moved agency     A       
22    22          4      104 2020-10-05    2021-12-01  restructure      <NA>    
23    23          4       NA 2021-12-02    2022-08-01  <NA>             <NA>    
24    24          4      109 2022-08-01    2022-10-28  relief           <NA>    
25    25          5      105 2022-10-02    2022-10-02  end of contract  E       
26    26          5       NA 2022-10-03    2022-10-14  <NA>             <NA>    
27    27          5      118 2022-10-14    2022-10-28  relief           <NA>    
28    28          5      118 2022-10-29    NA          relief           <NA>    
29    29          6      111 2020-10-16    2020-10-16  moved agency     A       
30    30          6      106 2020-08-01    2020-12-21  relief           <NA>    
31    31          6      106 2020-12-22    2021-12-21  promotion        <NA>    
32    32          6       NA 2021-12-22    2022-01-31  <NA>             <NA>    
33    33          6      120 2022-01-31    2022-12-23  relief           <NA>    
34    34          6      120 2022-12-24    2023-02-02  relief           <NA>    
35    35          6      120 2023-02-03    NA          relief           <NA>
```